# Calculate $E[X]$ for $X = \begin{cases} Z, & \text{if $Z<x$} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Tags: probability

> Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable, $$X = \begin{cases}
> Z,  & \text{if $Z<x$} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Calculate $E[X]$.

I did it as follow, but I am not sure if it is correct:

Note that $E[X]=E[E[X|Z]]$ and $E[X|Z] = \sum_x x\dfrac{P\{X=x,Z=z\}}{f(z)} = \Phi(x)/f(z)$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the culmulative distributive function for standard normal random variable.

So $E[X] = E[\Phi(x)/f(z)] = \Phi(x)E[1/f(z)] = \Phi(x)(0) = 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $Z \sim N(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes, a standard normal random variable. Sorry for typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
E[X] = E[Z\cdot 1_{\{Z<x\}}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{\{Z<x\}} ze^{-z^2/2} dz = \int_{-\infty}^{x} ze^{-z^2/2} dz = 1 - e^{-x^2/2}
$$

Comment: Got it. But may I ask what is wrong in my work？